# What is the working combination of the s3fs and fsspec version? ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_sync' from 'fsspec.asyn'

Tags: amazon-s3, python-s3fs, fsspec

I am using the latest version of s3fs-0.5.2 and fsspec-0.9.0, when import s3fs, encountered the following error:

```
File "/User/.conda/envs/py376/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .core import S3FileSystem, S3File
  File "/User/.conda/envs/py376/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 11, in <module>
    from fsspec.asyn import AsyncFileSystem, sync, sync_wrapper, maybe_sync
ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_sync' from 'fsspec.asyn' (/User/.conda/envs/py376/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py)
```

what is a working combination version of s3fs and fsspec?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my case the same happened. 'maybe_sync' was missing from 'fsspec.asyn'. For me, the following worked.

```
!pip install --upgrade awscli
!pip install --upgrade boto3
!pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/dask/s3fs
```

Comment: Please do not do this as a general setup. Upgrading all your packages in an environment like this can really break things (e.g., the botocore/aiobotocore pinning), and you should not rely on the main branch version unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of s3fs and fsspec as of today is 2021.11.0. The latest version on conda-forge is 2021.10.1 . Since the change to calendar versioning this year, the two are always released together and the dependency pinned, so that this kind of problem won't occur in the future.

I believe for fsspec 0.9.0, you need s3fs 0.6.0 .